# GeoDjango: 'No such file or directory' when creating PostGIS spatial database template

Tags: django, osx-lion, postgis, geodjango, django-postgresql

I am working on MacOS Lion. I have successfully set up the KyngChaos libraries for Postgres and PostGIS, as per the [official instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#kyngchaos-packages) with no problems.

I've reached the section on creating a [spatial database template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis), and now I'm hitting a problem:

```
$ psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql
/postgis.sql: No such file or directory
```

How can I debug this? Where does `postgis.sql` come from in the first place?

**UPDATE:**

I just made sure that `POSTGIS_SQL_PATH` was actually set, as follows:

```
$ POSTGIS_SQL_PATH=`pg_config --sharedir`/contrib/postgis-1.5
$ echo $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-1.5
$ psql -d template_postgis -f $POSTGIS_SQL_PATH/postgis.sql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql: No such file or directory
```

It looks as though `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3/share/postgresql/` exists but there is no `contrib` directory below it. Where does this come from?

Comment: looks like you installed postgresql, but not postgis... Can you make a global search for postgis.sql, and see if it's there ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not finding postgis.  Start by searching for postgis.sql.  If it is not found then install postgis.  If it is found then set your path appropriately.